# Django using mod_wsgi returns my 500 page

Tags: django, python-2.7, apache2, wsgi

When I run 127.0.0.1 on the web (company LAN) I get an 500 page, but the costume one I wrote to my specific django application.
I'm using apache 2.2 with mod_wsgi and django 1.5.1 (Python 2.7). I checked all of my settings so it should work fine but I can't understand why it's still returning a 500. 
Appreciate any help,
Alon

Comment: No port? Are you accessing localhost from the local machine?

Comment: The django app works in the local mode. Only when I try running my PC as the virtual machine for the web it returns the 500 page

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Changed the django settings. Apparently Debug was False, should be True